# How to remap ç and Ç keys into < and > symbols

Tags: keyboard-layout, remapping

I would like to do the remap in the title. Reason being is that my computer got a US keyboard, so it got 1 key less than the Spanish one.

As I don't really use **ç** or **Ç**, I wanted to sacrifice them on behalf of **<** and **>** that I use a lot.

Another option would be to map **alt+z** as **<** and **altGr+z** as **>**.

I've seen that Windows got something like Keytweak to achieve that, but I'm not sure how to achieve the same thing in Ubuntu.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to switch to an English keyboard layout which matches the US keyboard?

Comment: That's an option of course, but the rest of keyboards I use, home and work, are Spanish, so I would need to learn the new key distribution. And we need Ñ.

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the `es` symbols file.

```
--- /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/es.old
+++ /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/es
@@ -21,7 +21,7 @@
     key <AC11> { [dead_acute, dead_diaeresis, braceleft,   braceleft ] };
     key <TLDE> { [ masculine, ordfeminine,    backslash,   backslash ] };

-    key <BKSL> { [  ccedilla,   Ccedilla,   braceright,   dead_breve ] };
+    key <BKSL> { [      less,     greater,  braceright,   dead_breve ] };

     include "level3(ralt_switch)"
 };
```

Should be effective after next reboot.

Answer (score 2):

First to find the code of ç use:

```
$ xev
```

And press the `ç` key, this should display the codes of this key, in my case it is 51, and then run:

```
$ xmodmap -e "keycode 51 = less greater"
```

This will remap `ç` to `<` and `Ç` to `>`.

It worked very well for me, I hope it works for you.